# How to get fullAccountNumber in Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

Calling the `/accounts/{accountId}` endpoint with the include `fullAccountNumber` returns an error `Y821 - fullAccountNumber not supported`.

I'm doing:

```
curl -i -H "Api-version: 1.1" -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" -X 
GET https://production.api.yodlee.com/ysl/accounts/{accountId}
?container=bank&include=fullAccountNumber,holder,profile
```

Note: the line breaks are just for readability

How do you get `fullAccountNumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back to this because it's been more than a year and want to have a solution:

This was not possible with Yodlee and we went with a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the API correctly.  This feature needs to be enabled for your account, after approval from the Yodlee Security Office.  You can make an application through your account manager.

The error message should be updated to something more helpful, like *“fullAccountNumber feature is not enabled for account. Please contact Yodlee support.”*

Comment: Had been approved already. Didn't end up working and the Yodlee support wasn't helpful - ended up not using their service.